# Python 3.9.1. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, python-3.9

```
Python 3.9.1. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Как установить selenium?

Comment: Как обычно: `pip install seleinum`

Answer (score 4):

Вот так :

[`pip3 install selenium`](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)